# After installing ubuntu, windows does not recognize hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu alongside windows on my netbook. The ubuntu install corrupted my windows. So, I formatted the windows partition in ubuntu ntfs by itself. Only now boot windows does not recognize my hd! When I try to reinstall windows, windows does not find my hard drive. What do I do? Help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no explanation why the ubuntu "corrupted" your windows. Could you give more details on what message you got from windows, in order to reach this conclusion?

What do you mean you formatted the windows partition by itself? Which program did you use?

Could you re-open an Ubuntu program which administers hard disks (i.e. strike Alt+F2 , type `palimpsest`) and check what is the exact situation of your hard disk. It may be that NTFS format did not go all the way till the end.

I have no recent experience with installing Windos, but I also think that it would be enough to remove any formatting from a part of the hard disk and let windows install themselves there.

Comment: I formatted the hard drive for ubuntu with gparted, and then booted with windows cd, but he did not recognize any partitions on my hd